# TensorFlow debug: WARNING:tensorflow:Tensor._shape is private, use Tensor.shape instead. Tensor._shape will eventually be removed

Tags: python, debugging, tensorflow, visual-studio-code

I'm new (obviously) to python, but not so new to TensorFlow

I've been trying to debug my program using breakpoint, but everytime I try to check the content of a tensor in the variable view of my Visual Studio Code debugger, the content doesn't show I get this warning in the console:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Tensor._shape is private, use Tensor.shape instead. Tensor._shape will eventually be removed.

I'm a bit confused on how to fix this issue. Do I have to wait for an update of TensorFlow before it works?

Comment: Can you show us a small MWE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) program where what you describe is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Probably yes you may have to wait. In the debug mode a deprecated function is being called. 
You can print out the shape explicitly by calling  `var.shape()` in the code as a workaround. I know not very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply stop at the break point, and switch to DEBUG CONSOLE panel, and type var.shape. It's not that convenient, but at least you don't need to write any extra debug code in your code.